# How do I hide the parent folder of the user home folders in File Sharing?

Tags: server.app, file-sharing

I'm running 10.8 server and I have a folder named Users and it is the parent folder for every local network user's home folder. Now, when the user connects to the server he sees his home folder, but also the parent folder Users. He can even list the contents of it.

How can I hide this parent folder? I don't want it to show up at all when connecting. The only thing the users should see is their home folder. Nothing else. Since the Users folder is the parent folder, it cannot be unshared.

Answer (score 1):

Mac is mostly unix under the hood.  Try setting the permissions of the /Users folder to everyone only execute.

E.g. Currently:

bash-3.2# ls -ld /Volumes/Users
drwxrwxrwx  10 root  admin  510 23 May  2012 /Volumes/Users

bash-3.2# chmod o-rw /Volumes/Users

bash-3.2# ls -ld /Volumes/Users
drwxrwx--x  10 root  admin  510 23 May  2012 /Volumes/Users

OS X has addition access control tricks, so this may not work.

Comment: I realize this is an extraordinarily old thread, but I'm attempting to do the same thing, and OS X is certainly using an extended ACL for network home folder shares. Do you happen to have any idea if there is a combination of permissions that will allow a user to access their home directory, but not see the containing folder at all when connecting to the server?